# Android Google Places API- Is there any way to get the city from Place objects?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using the [autocomplete widget](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) of Google Place API for Android and getting a place object, but I am not able to extract the city of it, just only the [complete address](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getAddress()) as a text.

Apparently, the [Place](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place) interface does not have a method to return the city.

The city is the address componenets is Locality and Administrative Area Level 3, according this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter).

Does someone knows any way to get the city of the Place object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hack but it works. You can take the lat and lng from the `Place` object and find the city from the Geocoder.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);
 String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
 String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```